# App crashing when launched from the App Store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I've downloaded an app from the App Store. If I open it from the home screen, everything works fine. If I open it from within the App Store by tapping on "Open" it (the app) crashes at launch.

How can I fix this?

Comment: First I downloaded app from iTunes successfully.I open app from icon located in home screen  , app is working fine. Now I go on iTunes and on current app page I tap on Open ,Its crashing on launch.

Comment: Does it only happen with this one app (which one?) or with all? If, after a crash, you start it from the home screen, does it work or crash? Does the problem persist after a restart of the phone?

Comment: Delete the app and download it again.

Comment: @ROb Its not working , I tried.

Comment: @patrix I found in only my app and from the home screen all the thing working fine. only problem is when I am trying to open through iTunes.

Comment: Same issue here. Is there an any update?

Comment: Please add the name of the app.